# AS400 - Token "!" not valid

Tags: sql, string, db2, ibm-midrange, db2-400

I'm running a SQL query using **RUNSQL** into a CL program. This query is a basic SELECT statement and uses the exclamation mark to concatenate strings.

For years until yesterday, it worked fine. Now, out of nowhere, I've got a **SQL0104** message displaying **Token '!' not valid** every time I run the program.

If I run the query manually using STRSQL, it works.

Did this occur to someone ?

Best regards.

Answer (score 3):

DB2's operator for string concatenation is actually the double pipe `||`.

The [documentation says](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SS9UMF_12.1.0/ugr/ugr/tpc/dsq_use_concat_op.html):

> Use the concatenation operator (`||`) to join two values of an expression into a single string. In some non-English, single-byte character sets, the `||` can display as `!!` (exclamation marks) or other special characters.

So your issue may be caused by a change in the character set of your client. Just use the standard operator, and your code will work regardless.

Comment: Or, for better portability between different RDBMS, , use the CONCAT operator, as advised in the `Db2 for i` documentation here https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/ssw_ibm_i_74/db2/rbafzwtco.htm

Comment: @mao . . . Why would you NOT use the standard SQL operator if you want compatibility?  That does not sound like really sound advice.

Comment: @GordonLinoff - The more portable "standard" operator on modern systems worldwide is CONCAT. The issue with using pipe characters is internationalization. Remember that a significant portion of Db2 instances are on EBCDIC platforms, and when you involve translation between different encodings, bad things can happen to your precious pipe character.

Comment: @JohnY . . . There are standards committees for SQL.  "Standard" is not abstract, and `||` is the standard string concatenation operator.  The number of databases that support `concat()` is quite comparable to the number that support `||` -- and that includes Oracles bastardized support of only a two-argument form of the function.

Comment: @GordonLinoff - The "SQL Standard" is a *formal definition* and as such **is** abstract, as compared to *actual database implementations*. I think most of us, particularly working with databases for a living, are pragmatic people. If CONCAT is more likely to *actually work* then why would you **not** use it? If you know that CONCAT isn't going to work on a particular database you need to support, then that is of course a different story. The pipe character is a **known and documented trouble spot** for Db2, so why would you **not** avoid it when you **know** CONCAT will work?